# Android: Access OpenGL from other thread

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es-2.0

I am using the NDK on Android for OpenGL and I am trying to work around the quirks associated with GL when the app loses focus. I know that I can set a flag telling the system I want to keep the context, but that is unreliable.

I have it set up to reload shaders from file and re-upload the vertex data from local memory when the app resumes, but the textures are causing me some issues. I set up my code to pull the textures from GL in onPause  then push them back when a new context is created. Afterwards I realized that it doesn't work since I am trying to access GL data on a different thread.

Is there any reliable hack that can allow me to access the GL data here? Or even switch the context to the other thread?

As an extension to this question, is there any way to be notified before the context is destroyed? So that I only need to do this when absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was I set a boolean to tell the GL thread it is about to be put into the background. Then I had it pause The onPause thread for 5ms over and over until the GL thread indicated that it was done.

Not very elegant, and the app doesn't transition out, but it works.